# Unit testing in Spark with SQLContext implicits

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run multiple unit tests in Spark and have copied (and slightly adapted) the bit from the source code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Suite}

trait SharedSparkContext extends BeforeAndAfterAll {
  self: Suite =>

  @transient private var _sc: SparkContext = _
  @transient private var _sqlContext: SQLContext = _

  def sc: SparkContext = _sc
  def sqlContext: SQLContext = _sqlContext

  private var conf = new SparkConf(false)

  override def beforeAll() {
    super.beforeAll()
    _sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Test Suites", conf)
    _sqlContext = new SQLContext(_sc)
  }

  override def afterAll() {
    try {
      LocalSparkContext.stop(_sc)
      _sc = null
    } finally {
      super.afterAll()
    }
  }
}
```

The LocalSparkContext class with companion object are simply copied from the source.

I thought about using it as follows, which tells me that `stable identifier required` because the `def` `sqlContext` does not have the member `implicits`:

```
class MySuite extends FlatSpec with SharedSparkContext {
  import sqlContext.implicits._
  // ...
}
```

I have tried replacing it with the following, but that gives me null pointer exceptions:

```
class MySuite extends FlatSpec with SharedSparkContext {
  val sqlCtxt = sqlContext
  import sqlCtxt.implicits._
  // ...
}
```

I am using Spark 1.4.1 and I have set `parallelExecution in test := false`.

How can get this to work (without using additional packages)?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a trait, you can use a simple object that holds all your variables, here's what I do for my tests :

```
object TestConfiguration extends Serializable {

  private val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Tests")
      .setMaster("local")

  private lazy val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

  private lazy val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)

  def getSqlContext() = {
    sqlContext
  }  

}
```

Then, you'll be able to use the sqlContext in a test suite.

```
class MySuite extends FlatSpec with SharedSparkContext {
  val sqlCtxt = TestConfiguration.getSqlContext
  import sqlCtxt.implicits._
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That way I get the Spark environment values but a) I cannot mix in the configuration and b) I cannot make the configuration close the SparkContext after all the tests have been run. It works but it's not pretty.